# Special price for configurable products not displaying in product list page and not in product detailed page, Magento 2.0.7 used

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.0.7

Using Magento 2.0.7

Special price for a configurable product is not showing on the product page or in listing page, Added two simple product with different sizes SMALL and LARGE size and given special price for these two products it these special price details not showing in the product page. Special price work fine for the simple product.

Comment: in frontend side?